# Define which parent function has to be taken

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a child class which is derived from two parent classes (one public, one private). Each parent class has got a function which overloads the operator*. If I use this function in the child class, I get an error (ambiguous function), however I would like to use the method from the public parent.

```
class ParentA
{
 public:
   ParentA operator*(const ParentA & other);
};

class ParentB
{
 public:
   ParentB operator*(const ParentB & other);
};

class Child : public ParentA, private ParentB
{
   ...
};

int main()
{
   Child x,y;
   x*y;
   return 0;
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you very much,
Remo

Comment: You may try with `ret_type ret = ParentA::operator*( parameter );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the child class as follows (untested):

```
class Child : public ParentA, private ParentB {
public:
using ParentA::operator*;
... /*same as before*/
};
```